# If exists accumulate, otherwise insert in Hibernate

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, sql-update, sql-insert

As an example let's say I want to save the lines of code I've written on specific days of different months in a MySQL database using Hibernate. On the 5th of Janurary, I write 100 lines of code. I have not previously written any lines of code on this day, so it simply inserts the data.

A year passes and it's again the 5th of January. I write 50 lines of code this day, and I try to insert it into the database. The ID of day 5 and month 1 already exists, so it can't insert the data. In this case I would like it to simply add the lines of code the the already existing row, so it now says:

```
DAY.      MONTH.      LOC.
5.        1.          150.
```

What I'm currently doing is that every time I want to insert new data, I'm first making a `SELECT` query to check if the row already exists. If it does I create an `UPDATE` statement, otherwise I just create an `INSERT` statement. I'm working with a lot of data and have noticed that the operations involving my database are starting to take a long time. Therefore, I was wondering if there is a better, more efficient way to do this? Help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: See INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY

Comment: A replace and INSERT INTO ON DULICATE work when they find a violation, so if you have your column are unique.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for the `update... on duplicate key` syntax. This would look like:

```
insert into mytable(day, month, loc)
values(:day, :month, :loc)
on duplicate key update loc = loc + values(loc)
```

`:day`, `:month` and `:loc` represent the parameters that you give for `insert`.

For this to work, you need a unique constraint on `(day, month)` (or make that tuple of columns the primary key of your table).

When an `insert` occurs that would violate the unique constraint, MySQL goes to the `on duplicate key` clause, where we add the new `loc` value to the one already there in the existing row.

Comment: I tagged my entity with @SQLInsert() and wrote a statement similar to yours. I'm currently trying to insert an object which contains a list of objects that it has relationship with. When I do `repository.saveAll()` I now get the following error: `Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).` Any ideas?

Comment: I doesn't seem to work with `:day, :month, :loc`.. are question marks `?` required instead?

Comment: @Jesper: yes, possibly. Which placeholders are supported depend on the client you use.  I was just showing you how to use the `insert ... on duplicate key` syntax.

Comment: Well if I have to use `?` then I can't access the individual parameters to update them in the row, can I? In that case this solution won't work for me :/